# How to set background image in div for different screen resolutions?

Tags: php, css

I am developing a webpage in which I am setting background with help of div but my problem is that when the resolution of screen changes the image does not fit properly , it shows blank space on both side of screens on large screens.
Is there a way with which I can make a standard case which shall run for all screens .

This is how I am setting my div

```
mheaderimgs {
width:1007px;
margin:auto auto;
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS backckground-size property,

```
background-size:contain;
```

for more reference, see

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 1):

width:100% would strech it, If you make it a slightly bigger image it would shrink it in most cases only making you need 1 image.

As far as Im aware, there is no none-javascript method to get the size of the screen and then compare to set sizes

Answer (score 1):

Php doesn't know how big the clients screen is. Consider javascript or [Media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/)
.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this (CSS3 property) :

```
background-size: cover;
```

Otherwise, I think you can do it in javascript.